# Can't upload file on my own Apache server

Tags: php, html, apache

here is what I did.

Created an `/uploads` directory in `/var/www/html`

Created 2 files (still in `html` directory):

1st file (upload_page.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select file to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

2nd file (upload.php):

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)

}
```

When I use  the form (to upload a simple .txt file) and go to check in `/var/www/html/uploads`, the repository is empty...  Any advice ?

p.s: when I inspect the element with firefox, there is a 500 server error, but still I don't know why there is such an error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35641719/cant-upload-file-to-apache-2-2

Comment: @KamleshGupta Does not work for me I already did what adviced, read carefully please

Comment: a 500 error means a server error. Check your logs and/or use error reporting. Make sure that all folders can be written to. Many a time, that is the cause or plays a major role.

Answer (score 0):

**How to Debug Upload Scripts 101:**

1. Go through your own code and make sure you havent missed anything, unless you forgot to paste the entire code you are missing the closing tag for php `?>`
2. use absolute paths, `$target_dir = "uploads/";` would be `$target_dir = "/var/www/html/uploads"`, this is to just avoid issues in the future.
3. make sure your folder has `CHMOD 777` permissions, and if you are uploading files to sub directories in `uploads/` folder which is a good idea depending on how many files you expect to upload in that folder, make sure the sub folders are `CHMOD 777` as well.
4. if this did not help solve your issue, then login to your server's SSH and run the php script directly using `php upload.php` and see if it throws any errors. Alternatively you could change php's reporting from php.ini to see all the errors while you are in development phase. If there are any errors you see, solve them one at a time and try to upload a file after they are ALL taken care of.
5. If you are still experiencing an error, then its most probably a server configuration error. Make sure max upload size is set properly, make sure you are running PHP as a user with read and write permissions to that folder etc.

I know my response is not specific to your problem, but you have provided very little info!

Comment: 1) you don't need the closing tag for PHP if the script is PHP-only.

Comment: 2) much better to use relative paths using something like `__DIR__` or `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` - is both static but dynamic on different servers

Comment: 3) 777 is a very insecure modeset for a filesystem and should be reserved to last straw at all costs. 755 with correct ownership is better/safer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few days ago on Fedora Linux but was able to resolve by modifying the SELinux setting for the "data" directory in my website. I got the solution from [here](https://www.svnlabs.com/blogs/centos-7-selinux-apache-php-writeaccess-permission/).

I only needed these two commands to get the upload to work on the data folder inside the my website:

`sudo chown apache:apache -R /data` 
`sudo chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_rw_content_t data/`